# How to cancel kotlin coroutine if it takes longer than a certain period of time?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to cancel kotlin coroutine if it takes longer than a certain time.

This is what I am doing:

```
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val userOne = async(Dispatchers.IO) { Page_Load_Times() }.await()

        Log.d("Tag", "Long Running task: $userOne")
    }


suspend fun Page_Load_Times(): String? {
    val startTime: Long = 0
    var endTime: Long = 0

    delay(5000) // if it is greater a certain time, eg 1000, I want to cancel the thread and return 

    return "Hey there"

}
```

How to cancel kotlin coroutine if it takes longer than a certain period of time?

Answer (score 5):

There are built in suspending functions for that: [`withTimeout`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout.html) and [`withTimeoutOrNull`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout-or-null.html).

Just invoke it with specified timeout:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val userOne = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        withTimeoutOrNull(5000) { Page_Load_Times() }
    }

    Log.d("Tag", "Long Running task: $userOne")
}
```

Then your `userOne` becomes `null` if it times out.

Comment: Can I return any other value instead of null with `withTimeout()`? Or I have to check for null manually?

Comment: You can use `withTimeout` instead, catch `TimeoutCancellationException` and return whatever you want from the catch block.

Comment: Couldn't you use the elvis operator to catch the null and return something else? I'm not super familiar with coroutines so I'm not sure if you can put it after the coroutine block or if you'd need to wrap it in another block, but it seems like something you should be able to do!

Comment: @Rifat, you can always do `withTimeoutOrNull(time) { ... } ?: alternateValue`.

Comment: @cactustictacs of course using elvis operator is fine unless wrapped function itself returns `null` as a valid result in which case it becomes indiscernible

Answer (score 1):

I want to share a good example with you through the documentation. I hope it inspires.

```
 val job = launch {
        repeat(1000) { i ->
            println("job: I'm sleeping $i ...")
            delay(500L)
        }
    }
    delay(1300L) // delay a bit
    println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
    job.cancel() // cancels the job
    job.join() // waits for job's completion 
    println("main: Now I can quit.")
```

It produces the following output:

```
job: I'm sleeping 0 ...
job: I'm sleeping 1 ...
job: I'm sleeping 2 ...
main: I'm tired of waiting!
main: Now I can quit.
```

[Source-Doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dedicated method to watch and cancel jobs based on a timeout threshold. This approach allows you to perform any extra steps you may need after the timeout.

```
fun executeJob() {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch {
        repeat(10) { i ->
            println("job is working: $i")
            delay(500L)
        }

        println("job Ended")
    }

    watchJob(job, 2000L)
}

fun watchJob(job: Job, timeoutMs: Long) {

    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(timeoutMs)

        if (job.isActive) {
            job.cancel()
            println("job cancelled due to timeout")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

      withTimeout(5000L){
      if(isActive){
      //Do process you want to do
      }else{
      //return
      }
```

}

}

> Use withTimeOut for Time-Sensitive operations, For example in my case, I print 30 to 400 in 10 milliseconds. The code looks like below. if time passed more than 10 Milliseconds it returns from that block of code.

```
    GlobalScope.launch {

        withTimeout(10L){

            for (i in 30..400){
                if(isActive){
                    Log.d(TAG_WITHTIMEOUT,"$i")
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG_WITHTIMEOUT,"Time out Triggered")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1.withTimeout(TIME_YOUWANT_TOSET).
2.isActive - to check if TIME HAS PASSED or NOT in other words is that coroutine block is Active or not?